# why this shell script output so strange

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "===========3333333====="

if [ $0 == "test" ] || $0 == "all" ];then
    echo "---"
fi
```

endless loop output:

```
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
===========3333333=====
```

although I know the wrong is Missing square brackets
      if [ $0 == "test" ] || [ $0 == "all" ];then
but why output like that???

Answer (score 4):

Consider the line `if [ $0 == "test" ] || $0 == "all" ]`

This is of the form `if cmd1 || cmd2`, where cmd1 is `[ $0 == "test ]`
and cmd2 is `$0 == "all" ]`

That second command is invoking your script with arguments `==`, `all`, and `]`.  So you've got a recursion.

Remember, `[` is *not* part of the shell grammar.  It is just a command with the strange feature of requiring that its last argument be `]`.

Comment: While this makes sense, I am still not sure, which word initiated the recursion? Would you care to explain more?

Comment: There are some interesting things to note. Specifically, the script recurses when invoked as `./test.sh`, but *not* when invoked as `bash test.sh`, because that produces different $0.

Comment: @Inian `$0` is the name of the script, so `$0` invokes the script and causes the recursion.

Comment: Also note that the string comparison operator is `=` (`==` is a non-portable bashism to be avoided).

Answer (score 1):

```
$0 == "all" ];then
```

this section is starting the recursion. because $0 starting the script again.

for example below code is producing same result

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "===========3333333====="
$0 bash is not checking below!!!!!!!!!!
        echo "ok"
fi
```